# Making a class a delegate of more than 1 thing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates

I have 2 parts of my class that want it to be the delegate.

So I have:

```
@interface RewriteViewController : UIViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate>
```

And this causes an error with it saying it needs to be SKVocalizerDelegate.

And if i have:

```
@interface RewriteViewController : UIViewController <SKVocalizerDelegate>
```

It says the same about the `MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate`.

But putting:

```
@interface RewriteViewController : UIViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate> <SKVocalizerDelegate>
```

gives me a huge amount of errors. How can I make it the delegate for both?

Comment: check for the usage of the tag [xcode]: stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were almost there! You use a comma to show your class supports multiple delegates, like so:

```
@interface RewriteViewController : UIViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate, SKVocalizerDelegate>
```